# Change sharePoint URL link

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to change the SharePoint online URL link from `https://maemuza.sharepoint.com`
to `https://florance.sharepoint.com`, how can I achieve this.

This URL are in two different SharePoint 365 subscriptions, and I want to move one link from another subscription to another and change the second level domain on the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google is your friend: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/change-your-sharepoint-domain-name

There is no simple quick answer: read through the documentation and decide if that's for you.